# UML State machines for ViewModels - flags from states?

Tags: uml

I finally summoned up the courage to get to grips with UML State machines, driven by the need to implement and document a fairly complicated ViewModel for a WPF/C# app. The viewmodel has to handle several different editing states and incoming data sets, and so a SM is a good way to describe it.

I've used Altova's UModel to design the SM, which ended up with 3 simple states and 4 nested states. I can instantiate the state machine class generated by UModel in my ViewModel and hook up the SM events to my ICommands and event subscriptions, and use the SM actions to manipulate the data. So far, so good.

Now I need to set the boolean value of several VM properties based on the current SM state (e.g. IsChanged, IsEditing etc) These are designed to make binding a XAML view as easy as possible. How their values change as the SM transitions is a key part of the design, and so I'd like the values to be part of the SM diagram. It would also be great if they automatically became part of the generated SM class.

I've got as far as defining a stereotype with bool properties for each flag. I've applied this stereotype to each state, so that the correct values for each state are documented on the SM diagram.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to approach this ?
2. How hard will it be to generate properties on the SM class from
       the stereotyped attributes on each state ?

I'd really appreciate some guidance on whether I should go further down this route.I'm currently using/evaluating UModel, but will also look at Enterprise Architect. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to annotate your SM with [transitions containing triggers](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/protocol-state-machine-diagrams.html#protocol-transition) like `SetViewModelIsChanged(true)`. Add your current diagram to your question instead of the text describing it, then your question will be easier to read (and answer)

Comment: Having read up on this, it looks like it will work, in that it documents the flag state on the diagram, and I can generate code from it. Slightly better might be to put the method calls in the state Entry section. Thanks.